# Gridview with additional entries

Tags: c#, gridview, win-universal-app

I want to develop a control based on GridView.
It should load data from Item source, however it should also add some static entries (button for adding an item and adding a group), which will flow with other items in collection.

In other words, is there any way to add items of different type to GridView without interfering with original ItemSource

Windows Store/Windows Phone

EDIT:
Some additional ilustration:
GRIDVIEW:
|Item 1 from ItemSource| |Item 2 from ItemSource| |Item 3 from ItemSource|
|Additional item possible with different DataTemplate and with different type of content| |One more Additional item|

EDIT2:
I'm talking about Grid View in Windows Store / Windows Phone applications

Comment: Are you wanting to add the button(s) on every row, so that one or more of your columns has a button on every row?  Or are you trying to add one or more rows to the grid that have different content than the rest of the rows, with buttons instead of data?

Comment: Hopefully my edit will make more sense

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Listview for displaying data with view. Following code may help you. By using CellTemplate and  DataTemplate we can add additional data or controls.

```
<GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150">
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
```